# Why is Explicit Operator Not Invoked In Generic Method

Tags: c#, generics

I've distilled this question down to the simplest code sample I can think of. Why is the explicit operator not invoked from the generic method?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A a = new A();
        B b = (B)a; // works as expected
        b = Cast<B>(a);
    }

    static TResult Cast<TResult>(object o)
    {
        return (TResult)o; // throws Invalid Cast Exception
    }
}

class A
{
}

class B
{
    public static explicit operator B(A a)
    {
        return new B();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because a generic method has **one** set of IL, based around `TResult`. It doesn't do different IL per-caller. And the generic `TResult` **does not** have any operators.

Also: the operator here would need to be between `object` and `TResult`, and you **can't define** operators involving `object`.

For example: `Cast<int>` and `Cast<string>` and `Cast<Guid>` all have the exact same IL.

You can cheat with `dynamic`:

```
return (TResult)(dynamic)o;
```

Comment: wouldn't qualifying with a where TResult: B clause bring the operator into scope?

Comment: I don't understand. How does [Enumerable.Cast<TResult>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) differ from this?

Comment: @PatrickQuirk AFAIK, `Enumerable.Cast<TResult>` does not use operators (edit: verified - indeed, it does not).

Comment: @dthorpe, appears you have to go all the way to `static TResult Cast<TResult>(A o) where TResult:B` to get it to work.

Comment: @MarcGravell, but the source has a similar return statement (`yield return (TResult) obj;`, according to MS Source Server) to this example.  What do you mean by it "does not use operators"?

Comment: @PatrickQuirk I mean: that also won't work - it will throw the same exception that the code is currently

Comment: @MarcGravell Gotcha.  Tested and verified.  Thanks for talking through it with me

Comment: @PatrickQuirk that is exactly where I distilled this from. One of my coworkers ran into a casting issue converting items in a CheckBoxList. I showed him how to overload the explicit operator; expecting that to solve the problem. When it didn't, I started digging.

Answer (score 2):

What it comes down to is that the `implicit` and `explicit` operators aren't *true* conversion operators; they're entirely compile time syntactic sugar.  Once the code is compiled nothing about the conversion operators remains.

When the compiler sees:

```
B b = (B) new A();
```

It says, "is there any native conversion (implicit or explicit) from an `A` to a `B`?" (This would be the case if `A` extended `B`, for example), or for one of the few special cased language conversions such as `double` to `int` (implicit) or `int` to `double` (explicit).)

If not, it then looks for user defined conversion operators (it only looks in the definition of `A` and `B`, it doesn't look in the definition of `C` for an implicit conversion from `A` and to `B`, for example).  If it finds one, then it injects that operator as a static method call, so the code ends up looking like:

```
B b = B.SomeAutogneratedName(new A());
```

That way by the time you get to runtime it's just executing another method, something the runtime knows how to do.  The only actual *runtime* conversion operators that are allowed are the handful baked into the language (i.e. from any base type to a parent type, and between certain primitive types).